# making a batch file that creates a specific vbs file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

im making a batch file that creates a vbs script, which sends key inputs, but this doesn't seem to echo the "%" into the script.

```
echo set shell = createobject ("wscript.shell")> tempoary.vbs    
echo shell.SendKeys "%f" >> tempoary.vbs    
start tempoary.vbs
```

Comment: in a batch file % has to be escaped with another % so try `%%f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is used for variables in a batch file and so your `batch` program is attempting to substitute your variable `%f` with it's value. Of course there is no such variable, so you are getting nothing.

You should be able to escape the `%` so it is treated as a literal percent:

```
echo shell.SendKeys "%%f" >> tempoary.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this :

1. To escape special character like `)` you should add a carret `^)`
2. To escape special character like `%` you should add `%%`

***further reading :*** ***[Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)***

```dos
@echo off
(
echo set shell = createobject ("wscript.shell"^)
echo shell.SendKeys "%%f" 
)> tempoary.vbs    
start "" tempoary.vbs
```